# How to create reaction in a mobx store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I want to automatically get the user data like below but I get an error at the observe line:

> Uncaught Error: [mobx] Invariant failed: Cannot obtain atom from [object Object]

```
class AuthStore {

 @observable loggedIn = false;
 @observable userData;

  constructor() {
    observe(this, 'loggedIn', (change) => {
          if (change.loggedIn) {
            this.getUserData();
          }
    });
  }

  async getUserData() {
    const response = await ajax({
      url: '/users/me',
      method: 'GET'
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    //todo handle some errors here
    this.userData = data.user;
  }

}
```

Comment: which MobX version are you using? There was a bug in 2.2.2 where the loggedIn attribute might be not initialized yet in the constructor when using Babel. This is fixed in 2.3 and as work around you could insert a line in the constructor that reads: 'this.loggedIn;'

Comment: yes constructor initialization solved it. put it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved it already? If not, try using `reaction` instead of `observe`:

```js
reaction(
  () => this.loggedIn,
  loggedIn => loggedIn && this.getUserData()
)
```